# Выполнить иконку чуть меньше svg

Tags: css3, html5, svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="white">
     <path d="M 22.500353,10.482272 H 5.2851745 L 12.806219,2.7788559 c 0.601069,-0.6156419 0.601069,-1.625926 0,-2.24156786 -0.601067,-0.61564189 -1.572021,-0.61564189 -2.173088,0 L 0.47663774,10.940057 c -0.6010671,0.615642 -0.6010671,1.610139 0,2.225783 L 10.633131,23.568609 c 0.601067,0.615641 1.572021,0.615641 2.173088,0 0.601069,-0.615643 0.601069,-1.610141 0,-2.225782 L 5.2851745,13.639409 H 22.500353 c 0.847659,0 1.541198,-0.710354 1.541198,-1.578568 0,-0.868213 -0.693539,-1.578569 -1.541198,-1.578569 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Не удается иконку сделать чуть поменьше, то есть отступы по краям чуть побольше.

Каждый раз добавляется параметр transform:matrix(0.81,0,0,0.81,2.2864019,2.2900601). Кто нибудь может это сделать, так чтобы данного параметра не было?

Вторая проба, привести иконку к base64, сколько не вытался, не отображается через background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добавить отступы нужно отредактировать svg. Добавить внутрь пустой rect и увеличить viewport на размер отступов.

В Base64 не обязательно кодировать, чтобы добавить изображение на фон. Достаточно указать путь к svg файлу и обязательно указать размеры элемента `width` и `height`.

```
background: url("icon.svg");
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

Отредактированный svg, кодированный в Base64

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #000000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.icon {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```